# How to make the perfomance faster when ajax calls webmethods in asp.net

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

```
[Play.aspx]
[asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
.....
viewvideo(videoid)
.......
[/asp>
[Video.js]
function viewvideo(videoid) 
{
    varVideoid = videoid;
    $("#video").empty();
    var data = Ajax("../Ajax/Webmethod.aspx/getviewvideo", { videoid: videoid });
}
[function.js]
function Ajax(url, _data) {
    var obj;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(_data),
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Some Error");
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
[Webmethod.aspx.cs]
 [WebMethod]
    public static string getviewvideo(string videoid)
    {
        databasesss db = new databasesss();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
.........................
        }
        return js.Serialize(v);
    }
```

Hi,
I have speed issue when ajax calls webmethod,
How can I improve the perfomance
Any comment would be helpful 
Thank you

ps)I have tried to use  but there are many things to edit so I am looking for another way

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I don't have many knowlage for ajax so I thought the code has something worng

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following list one by one.

**1.** check SP code and check execution time and try to reduce Time(Check size of data)

**2.** call web method and check execution time.

**3.** Ajax just a call web method for get a data and set this data. so do not a more time.